# File.Open doesn't throw IOException for already open file

Tags: c#, ioexception, system.io.fileinfo

This always returns `false` regardless of whether `file` is already open or closed.

It worked fine until yesterday; today it doesn't work as expected.

```
public bool isOpen(FileInfo file)
{
    FileStream stream = null;

    try
    {
        stream = file.Open(FileMode.Open);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Logger.Error(ex.Message);
        return true;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (stream != null)
            stream.Close();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Try to search for StackOverflow for "check file open [c#]" - there are already a couple of related questions with answers. Note that checking if a file is open before doing or not doing something on it is usually moot - if that is what you are really after - because that information is already obsolete once you have it. For details, also see answers/comments to said other/related questions.

Comment: Did you change your environment from debug to release? The compiler may be noticing that you don't use stream anyway and basically reducing the function to `return false`.

Comment: As an aside, use a [`using`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) statement to guarantee disposal of the stream.